# UIGestureRecognizer stops working after first use

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, tvos

In my tvOS app I have a collection view with cells that represent movies.

I attached 2 gesture recognizers to the view:

1. Go to movie details on selection tap
2. Play movie directly (with an Apple TV Remote dedicated Play button)

---

```
    let posterTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ListViewController.movieSelect(_:)))
    posterTap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(posterTap)

    let posterPlay = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ListViewController.moviePlay(_:)))
    posterPlay.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(posterPlay)
```

And the respected methods

```
func movieSelect(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let cell = UIScreen.mainScreen().focusedView as? ItemCollectionViewCell {
        let item = ItemViewController(nibName: "ItemViewController", bundle: nil)
        item.item = cell.data
        self.presentViewController(item, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func moviePlay(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let cell = UIScreen.mainScreen().focusedView as? ItemCollectionViewCell {
        let data = cell.data
        // TLDR;
        // Passing data to AVPlayerViewController and presenting it + start playing the movie.
    }
}
```

Everything seem to work, apart from the fact that when I stop playing the movie and coming back to the list (by closing the `AVPlayerViewController`), my second gesture recognizer (Play button) no longer works. It is still there if I check with `print(self.view.gestureRecognizers)` but `moviePlay()` is never called again no matter what.

Is there a way to debug this? What may cause this issue? I'm thinking this is caused by `UIGestureRecognizerState` being still in "use"? Or maybe something like that. At this point I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I've experience *weirdness* with gesture recognizers on **tvOS**.  In my case, for some reason, the app behaved as if gesture recognizers were lingering on after container view had been dismissed.  Oddly enough, I've observed this *weirdness* when launching and closing `AVPlayerViewController` a few times as well.

What I did to fix this was to remove use of gesture recognizers and overriding `pressesEnded` method instead.

I hope this helps.